# Trying to integrate Stripe with salesforce using stripe SDK. Can some one tell how to do it?

Tags: integration

Stripe SDL Link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/04/recurring-billing-with-the-stripe-sdk-for-salesforce.html

If some one has already implemented please Help !